# widget won't display until screen size changed

Tags: python, widget, kivy

I want to make a game and I have chosen Kivy for my GUI, as I have written my backend in Python. I am currently using `runTouchApp(appwindow)` to run the application, where `appwindow` is a `FloatLayout()` object. The way I update my screen is that I run `appwindow.clear_widgets()` and `then appwindow.add_widget(new_screen)` where `new_screen` is the layout object which contains all other widgets.

It worked fine till now, but for some reason I can't understand the widget I add gets loaded properly (according to the cmd running in the background) but won't display till I change the screen size.

Here is a sample code:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.1.1')
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image


appwindow = FloatLayout()
class MenuScreen():
    def build(self):
        bg = Image(source = 'Images/bg/bg.jpg',allow_stretch= True,keep_ratio= False)
        box = BoxLayout(orientation = 'vertical')
        menu_items = []
        for i in range (0,4):
            button = Button(text = 'Menu item no:'+str(i))
            button.bind(state = checkMenuPress)
            menu_items.append(button)
        for button in menu_items:
            box.add_widget(button)
        floater = FloatLayout(size = bg.size)
        floater.add_widget(bg)
        floater.add_widget(box)
        floater.size_hint = 1,1
        return floater
class SecondScreen():
    def build(self):
        bg = Image(source = 'Images/bg/bg.jpg',allow_stretch= True,keep_ratio= False)
        box = BoxLayout(orientation = 'vertical')
        box.add_widget(bg)
        return box
def checkMenuPress(button,*args):
    if button.state == 'normal':
        sc = SecondScreen().build()
        appwindow.clear_widgets()
        appwindow.add_widget(sc)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    menuscreen = MenuScreen().build()
    appwindow.add_widget(menuscreen)
    runTouchApp(appwindow)
```

Comment: Please provide a short working example of your problem. It's impossible to debug with so little information.

Comment: the above code works fine but after few of screen updates the final screen just shows the background image and labels. th buttons and other images are loaded but not displayed till the window size is changed

Answer (score 0):

Okay, there are a few things wrong here. To create an app, you should subclass kivy.app.App and have it's build method return the "root" widget. Only this class needs build method: any others are redundant.

Once you have a root widget, it's just a matter of inserting and removing widgets. This is how I would approach it.

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.1.1')
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.app import App


class MenuScreen(App):
    floater = None

    def build(self):
        bg = Image(source='Images/bg/bg.jpg',
                   allow_stretch= True,
                   keep_ratio= False)
        box = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        menu_items = []
        for i in range(0, 4):
            button = Button(text='Menu item no:'+str(i))
            button.bind(state=self.checkMenuPress)
            menu_items.append(button)
        for button in menu_items:
            box.add_widget(button)
        self.floater = FloatLayout(size=bg.size)
        self.floater.add_widget(bg)
        self.floater.add_widget(box)
        self.floater.size_hint = 1, 1
        return self.floater

    def checkMenuPress(self, button,*args):
        if button.state == 'normal':
            self.floater.clear_widgets()
            self.floater.add_widget(SecondScreen())


class SecondScreen(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SecondScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget(Image(source='Images/bg/bg.jpg',
                              allow_stretch=True,
                              keep_ratio=False))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MenuScreen().run()
```

Comment: i have updated my code accordingly but in vain. my code has definately become clearer but still does not solve the issue. the last window still does not update. Is there a kivy function to update the widgets or app?
Also what will be the equivalent for stopTouchApp() in such a structure?

Comment: When you say that last window does not update, I'm not sure what you mean. The button click switches to the second screen which shows the picture? But I'm not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: Sorry, premature post...;-) Not sure what you are trying to do, but is this something like it? Just drop some images into the "Images" subfolder....

https://gist.github.com/Zen-CODE/9115401

Comment: this is just a sample code. where i have just displayed a background image in second screen i have a complex screen of a grid layout and each location a box layout with -ve spacings and each widget in the box layout is a custom button widget where there is a image on each button or a simple image. when i run my actual screen as a seperate app it loads perfectly but when the same screen is loaded as a child widget in the above fashion the background image, labels and the buttons are loaded without any other image ( including the ones that are on the buttons).

Comment: Have you tried using the screenmanager to switch between screens, instead of clearing the widgets?

http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html

That would probably be a cleaner approach than clearing the widgets and adding them each time? After all, transitioning between different screens is what the ScreenManager is built for...

Comment: i am new to kivy so did not come screenmanager anywhere.. I shall try this.. looks promising..

Comment: My app mow crashes with 'Exception Code : c0000005' where it was supposed to show the screen. (I work on Windows 7 64bit Home Premium)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so here's a quick rework of the example using Screens. It's difficult without knowing what you are trying to do, so if this does not help, try writing  summary of the behavior you are looking for.

```
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen


class MenuScreen(Screen):
    """
    The Screen containing the menu
    """
    def __init__(self, sm, **kwargs):
        super(MenuScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.sm = sm  # Store a reference to the screen manager

        bg = Image(source='Images/bg/bg.jpg',
                   allow_stretch= True,
                   keep_ratio= False)
        box = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        menu_items = []
        for i in range(0, 4):
            button = Button(text='Menu item no:'+str(i))
            button.bind(state=self.check_menu_press)
            menu_items.append(button)
        for button in menu_items:
            box.add_widget(button)
        floater = FloatLayout(size=bg.size)
        floater.add_widget(bg)
        floater.add_widget(box)
        floater.size_hint = 1, 1
        self.add_widget(floater)

    def check_menu_press(self, button, *args):
        if button.state == 'normal':
            self.sm.current = "second"


class SecondScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, sm, **kwargs):
        super(SecondScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget(Image(source='Images/bg/bg.jpg',
                              allow_stretch=True,
                              keep_ratio=False))
        self.sm = sm  # Store a reference to the screen manager

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        self.sm.current = "menu"


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(sm, name="menu"))
        sm.add_widget(SecondScreen(sm, name="second"))
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

Comment: Sorry, but I see no module? If you could post runnable code, I could try and get it to work....

Answer (score 0):

looks like i have found a source of the crashing problem. I had used multi-threading for a server client interaction. i had been using two extra threads, one for the server and another for the client. If i try to integrate the client thread with the GUI it raises another problem. even if the socket.recv() is after the ScreenManager.current = "newscreen" line, the app's screen does not change. it freezes in the way i left it. it resumes only after it gets a message from the server.